# WordPress not loading when I enter IP address as URL, I just get the default Ubuntu page (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, apache2

I have PHP, MySQL, Apache2 and WordPress installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 system by following this very recent guide step by step: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-using-lamp-stack/.

The final step is to enter your public IP address as the URL. E.g. http://Your_IP_Address.

However, I get the typical Ubuntu page that shows when everything is working.

So it seems that the only thing not installed properly is WordPress. This is likely as it's my first time installing it.

I have the contents in the 'var' and the 'tmp' directories. Is this typical?

This is my apache2 config:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Does anyone even know which file(s) I should troubleshoot?

Comment: Accessing such projects via IP address does not make the most sense to begin with, IMHO. You should rather set up a proper VirtualHost and a local host name for development. (Unless you have a specific requirement that makes it necessary to be able to access the whole thing via IP?)

Comment: Where did you installed your WordPress site? If this is the only site on this machine it should go under the `/var/www/html/` folder. Also, in the `<Directory /var/www>` directive, change the `AllowOverride` to `All`

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I'm merely following the guide. I would usually use a local host name or Vagrant for my PHP and Laravel projects. I'm not sure why the guide instructs you to use your IP address. I just don't know how to use a VirtualHost for WordPress.

Comment: I've copied the files into /var/www/html and I get the same result. Which file is the ```<Directory /var/www>``` in?

Answer (score 0):

please use following snippet

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted

Comment: Thanks but which file?